# jQuery AJAX - data parameter blank at controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using `ASP.NET MVC 3`, I'm making a jQuery (`ver 1.7.1`) AJAX call, like I've done a billion times. However, I've noted something strange. **The following call works fine**:

```
// license object
var license = {
    City: "New York",
    CompanyID: 1,
    County: "N/A",
    IsActive: true
};
// make the request
var $req = $.post('/License/theLicense', license); 
$req.success(function () {
    // this works!
});


[HttpPost]
public void Save(License theLicense)
{
    // save
}
```

**However, when I specify the data parameter for the controller it doesn't register at the controller**

```
// license object
var license = {
    City: "New York",
    CompanyID: 1,
    County: "N/A",
    IsActive: true
};
// make the request
// this time the controller parameter is specified
// the object will be blank at the server
var $req = $.post('/License/theLicense', { theLicense: license });
$req.success(function () {
    // this does not work
});
```

**The object is blank at the controller as shown below**

[image]

This is annoying because I will need to pass another data parameter, but I can't due to this issue.

**NOTE:** The JSON is identical to the POCO.

**Why is it when I specify the data parameter the object shows up blank at the controller, but when I don't it's just fine?**

Comment: Can the down voter actually comment on why they down voted? That's a little ridiculous. I spent a lot of time coming up the this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the POCO deserializer gets caught on for strange reason. I have seen it before where my JSON object exactly matches the POCO and it still won't deserialize.

When this happens I usually send the object to the server as a JSON string and then deserialize it on the server. I personally use ServiceStack.Text because it is the fastest.

So your jQuery would go like this:

```
var license = {
    City: "New York",
    CompanyID: 1,
    County: "N/A",
    IsActive: true
};

var $req = $.post('/License/theLicense', JSON.stringify(license));
```

Then your Controller would take in a string parameter (json) to deserialize the object:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public void Save(string json)
   {
       License theLicense = JsonSerializer<License>.DeserializeJsonString(json);
       // save
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

this happens because you are sending an object containing license as member but your controller expecting a `License`  object.

you must declare a wrapper class for your data like this:

```
  public Class MyWrapperClass
  {
      public License theLicense;
      //declare other extra properties here  
  }
```

and your controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public void Save(MyWrapperClass thewrraper)
{
    var license = thewrapper.theLicense;
    // save
}
```

**Edit:**
   try surrounding your json object's member with quotations.eg(`{"theLicense": license }`)

Comment: I like this solution, but I'm my license class is still blank within the wrapper class.

Comment: are you sure json is exactly same as POCO?

Comment: put a FormCollection as parameter in your controller action and check if correct data is coming from client?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JS:

```
// license object
var license = {
    City: "New York",
    CompanyID: 1,
    County: "N/A",
    IsActive: true
};

var $req = $.post('/License/Save', { theLicense: license });
$req.success(function () {
    // this does not work
});
```

.NET

```
public class LicenseController: Controller 
{
   ...

   [HttpPost]
   public void Save(License theLicense)
   {
       // save
   }

   ...
}
```